# Bootstrap 3 - Featured Product Slider to show one product at a time at mobile size

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am implementing a carousel of featured products on my ecommerce site.

I would like it to show only one of the products at mobile size, but when I use col-sm-12 it puts all of the thumbnails in one long column. I'd like it to maintain the carousel functionality so that you can still scroll through each of the products, just one by one at mobile size.

I am using Bootstrap 3.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <div class="row-fluid col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3>Shop by Brand</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <!-- Controls -->
                        <div class="controls pull-right hidden-xs">
                            <a class="left fa fa-chevron-left btn btn" href="#carousel-example"
                               data-slide="prev"></a><a class="right fa fa-chevron-right btn" href="#carousel-example"
                                                        data-slide="next"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="col-item">
                                       

                                        <div class="photo">
                                            <img src="http://www.prepbootstrap.com/Content/images/template/productslider/product_001.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <div class="separator clear-left">
                                                <p class="btn-add">
                                                <a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Shop Now</a>
                                                </p>
                                                
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clearfix">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="col-item">


                                        <div class="photo">
                                            <img src="http://www.prepbootstrap.com/Content/images/template/productslider/product_001.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <div class="separator clear-left">
                                                <p class="btn-add">
                                                    <a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Shop Now</a>
                                                </p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clearfix">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="col-item">


                                        <div class="photo">
                                            <img src="http://www.prepbootstrap.com/Content/images/template/productslider/product_001.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <div class="separator clear-left">
                                                <p class="btn-add">
                                                    <a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Shop Now</a>
                                                </p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clearfix">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="col-item">


                                        <div class="photo">
                                            <img src="http://www.prepbootstrap.com/Content/images/template/productslider/product_001.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <div class="separator clear-left">
                                                <p class="btn-add">
                                                    <a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Shop Now</a>
                                                </p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clearfix">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="col-item">


                                        <div class="photo">
                                            <img src="http://www.prepbootstrap.com/Content/images/template/productslider/product_001.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <div class="separator clear-left">
                                                <p class="btn-add">
                                                    <a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Shop Now</a>
                                                </p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clearfix">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="col-item">


                                        <div class="photo">
                                            <img src="http://www.prepbootstrap.com/Content/images/template/productslider/product_001.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <div class="separator clear-left">
                                                <p class="btn-add">
                                                    <a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Shop Now</a>
                                                </p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clearfix">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="col-item">


                                        <div class="photo">
                                            <img src="http://www.prepbootstrap.com/Content/images/template/productslider/product_001.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <div class="separator clear-left">
                                                <p class="btn-add">
                                                    <a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Shop Now</a>
                                                </p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clearfix">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="col-item">


                                        <div class="photo">
                                            <img src="http://www.prepbootstrap.com/Content/images/template/productslider/product_001.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="a" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <div class="separator clear-left">
                                                <p class="btn-add">
                                                    <a href="#" class="hidden-sm">Shop Now</a>
                                                </p>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clearfix">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: You need to put them each in a 12 column row so that each one takes up the full slide width. The carousel will treat the content of the div as its own slide so long as your using the full width of the row.

Comment: When I do that, it lists all of the products in one vertical column at mobile size. Also, I want multiple items so show at larger screen sizes.

Comment: Each image also needs to be inside of an item wrapper.

<div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="item">
               <img src="yourimage.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
               <img src="yourimage2.jpg">
          </div>
    </div>